# Reducing number of using in C#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, using, sqlclient

My question might be silly or may not be a question at all, but here it goes..

I am performing quite some database operations in my ASP.net MVC project where I am creating two objects each and every time namely, `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand`.

I have shown an example below

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("sRegisterUser", connection))
  {
```

I am doing all these different operations inside **one class under different methods.**

My question is how can I reduce the creation of these objects each and every time? How can I create them globally

PS: sRegisterUser is a stored procedure, like wise other methods use different procedures which gets different values as parameters.

Please help me out.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Uhh... You *should* create and dispose them every time. You could try to move the creation to one, common method (in one way or another), but you still should create and dispose the connection and command.

Comment: Sounds like you need Repository Pattern to start with to separate out actual business logic and data access.

Comment: Can you explain me a bit more on Repository Pattern

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The answer is, **don't.** You **do not** want to share these objects, you are using them appropriately.

Comment: I was suggested to use using while used these objects but can you say me how is it advantageous?

Comment: @RandomUser, these classes were built to be used like this. Creating a `new SqlConnection` does not mean analogously creating a *new pipe* to the SQL Server. Furthermore, they have unmanaged resources in them, that's why they implement `IDisposable`, those resources need cleaned up. **Anything** that implements `IDisposable` is built to be created, used, and disposed; **every time.**

Comment: Opening up a database connection uses resources, you don't want to hold on to those resources if you have no need for them. What the using does is it frees(disposes) those resources. At the end of the using block internally a dispose method is called to free up those resources

Comment: @RandomUser, finally, unlike many other documents Microsoft **actually spells out** how to use the `SqlConnection` object (and its siblings) here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx.

Comment: but you may create a custom `DbCommandContext : IDisposable` class that creates both connection and command in its ctor and disposes both in its IDiposable implementation. So your actual code only contains one `using(DbCommandContext ctx = new DbCommandContext())` instead of both.

Comment: @eFloh: that can be done. I generally recommend against it because a) now the disposing is on your shoulders so you need to absolutely harden that class and b) there is no real benefit IMO. Adding such overhead for a single `using` statement generally causes problems.

Comment: @Michael: I second your opinion, our company also doesn't use such wrappers, but if you favor clean "user code" over additional (and as you stated possibly faulty) code, this is a nice way. Other techniques may leave out the outer parentheses, what I don't recommend either. (consider addind a statement between these lines later... uh-oh...)

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I've used the db context pattern for five years now and so far it's been a huge help. Code is more concise, easier to both read and write, data helper methods needs less parameters, the risk of leaving an object undisposed is close to zero and it also provides a friendly abstraction level over transaction handling. The core is compatible with pretty much any ADO.NET providers and can be extended to better suit the particular needs and features of a specific one. I would definitely recommend that approach.

Answer (score 3):

You don't. You either keep the object alive, which is bad. Or you dispose it the way you should, and currently do.

So, why do you have use `using`?

Since `using` is necessary for disposing the handles in Windows.

You could also write this, which is similar to using `using`:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
connection.Close();
connection.Dispose();
```

`using` also disposes when the code above throws an error. Using `using` is actually the shortest way to code this.

So the error-save version should be:

```
SqlConnection connection;

try
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

    ...

    connection.Close();
}
finally
{
    connection.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: For it to be truly similar to `using`, you'd want the `Close()` and `Dispose()` calls in a `finally` block

Comment: @ledbutter: Thanks. Posted it this way to make the error handling problem clear. Adjusted answer with error-save version.

Answer (score 1):

As others already said, there is *nothing* wrong with what you're doing right now. ADO.NET objects are meant to be used and disposed of. As a rule of thumb you should **create them as late as possible** and **dispose of them as soon as possible**.

With that being said, I understand what you're trying to do here and I do have a few ideas you might be interested in for making your life easier while keeping good programming practices.

If you want to make the code more concise you can chain `using` statements:

```
using (var cn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(yourQuery, cn))
{
    // do stuff
}
```

The IDE will not try to indent the second block, making it easier on you to read.

You can also create an [abstraction layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstraction_layer) for your procedure:

```
public static class Procedures
{
    public static void RegisterUser() // add whatever parameters you need
    {
        using (var cn = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(yourQuery, cn))
        {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

From then on you can execute your procedure simply by calling:

```
Procedures.RegisterUser();
```

Another alternative is to introduce a [factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) to get your objects. This alone won't reduce their number but it might help in getting them all set up already (ie correct connection string).

You also can be creative and combine the two patterns. A custom class implementing `IDisposable` can take care of creating the necessary ADO objects, open the connection, execute your query, close the connection and dispose of any objects that needs disposal when it is itself disposed of.

Take your pick.

Comment: Does chain work similar to what I have used? Sorry for being silly

Comment: @RandomUser the exact same, only it will be in one block rather than two. Might be easier on you to write, indent and eventually read.

Comment: @RandomUser: in fact, you could remove the brackets since there is only one statement in the first `using`.